# Empty theme.css when trying to use original Bootstrap 3 files

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, compilation, less, impresspages

I tried to adopt the Air theme insinde the current IP. 
The problem is that the resulting theme.css stays empty, Ithink due to a compilation error.

I have replaces the original less files of the theme inside the assets/less-subfolder by the twitter Bootstrap less files.

As soon as I include more than ipContent.less and variables.less (for example the original Bootstrap grid.less) the resulting css file becomes empty.

Does anybody have an idea? It's not a file permission issue that's sure. 
Something about missing variables I suppose.

Thank you and cheers from Hamburg, 
Thomas

Comment: System -> Log should show you at least some information about the problem. It could definitely be a variables issue.

Comment: Thank you! Got it I think. 
I'll stick to the IP-implemented Bootstrap. 
Shame on me that I haven't realized IP actually is BS3 from the base - great! :-)